# Problem executing multiple powershell scripts from a batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a .bat that calls 3 PowerShell scripts
Basically the bat file looks like this

```
PScript1
Pscript2
Pscript3
```

After the Pscript1 the batch file does not execute Pscript2 or Pscript3, it stops and does not seem to return control to the batch file. Does anyone know what might cause this problem ?

Comment: please post your batch script. you probably need to use `call` or `start /wait` before each of their names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a batch file you would typically use `&&` or `||` depending on whether or not you wanted the subsequent commands to run based on the success of previous commands e.g.:

```
powershell.exe .\PScript1.ps1 && powershell.exe .\PScript2.ps1
```

This invocation would execute the following command only if the preceeding command succeeded.  You also need to specify powershell.exe as the EXE.  The default action for a `.ps1` is to open the file for editing.